# AppleScript Slider "start" Value

Tags: xcode, macos, slider, applescript

I want to set a slider with a click to a value via variable, i got that that far:

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    on sliderButton_(sender)
        set slider to 100
    end sliderButton_
end script
```

My Button is in the .xib file linked to "sliderButton" and the slider is linked to slider, but if i click on the button nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific when you say you are linking the slider. Are you trying to use a Reference Outlet or a Binding to the slider's value? Cause you're showing neither in your code.

You'd need:

```
property mySlider: "100"
```

and then bind the slider's value to that variable.
Or, if you're using a reference outlet, you'd need:

```
property mySlider: missing value
```

And then call something like:

```
mySlider's setIntegerValue_("100" as integer)
```